# How can I access a TextView in a Nested Preference Screen

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, textview, android-preferences, android

I am trying to reach and update TextView through ListPreference which is located in a child preference screen but it wasn't successful

FILE: "preference.xml"

```
PreferenceScreen>

  blah... blah...

    <PreferenceScreen>

         <ListPreference
            android:id="@+id/pref_key_myNotification_time"
            android:key="@string/pref_key_myNotificationTime"
            android:title="@string/choose_time_hour_title"
            android:defaultValue="24 Hours"
            android:entries="@array/notify_hour"
            android:entryValues="@array/notify_hourValues"
           android:layout="@layout/my_notifications_layout"/>

    </PreferenceScreen>

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

FILE: "my_notification_layout.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <LinearLayout style="@style/myLayoutStyle"
                android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">

    <TextView style="@style/myPrefStyle"
              android:text="Pick Notification Hours"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/notifyMe_chooseTime_textView"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:text="24 Hours"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <View style="@style/PrefDivider"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in my "preference_frag.java"  I tried to access "notifyMe_chooseTime_textView" but failed!!

```
@Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
  {
/*  This doesn’t seem to be working!! */
if (pref.getKey().equals(“key_notifyMeChooseTime”))
      {
        TextView tvHours = (TextView) getView().findViewById(“notifyMe_chooseTime_textView”);
        tvHours.setText(pref.getEntry().toString());
}
  }
```

I'd greatly appreciate if anyone of you can find a solution for it!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android not sure if this will work but try this

```
@Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
  {
/*  This doesn’t seem to be working!! */
if (pref.getKey().equals(“key_notifyMeChooseTime”))
    {
     TextView tvHours = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.notifyMe_chooseTime_textView);
      tvHours.setText(pref.getEntry().toString()); 
}
 }
```

Comment: Yes, in fact, R.id.notifyMe_chooseTime_textView is how I am done on my project.  Not really accessable